# How can uninstall an app whose name consists of garbled characters from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display, language, locale

I want to uninstall the app whose name consists of garbled characters.

[image]

Comment: I am going to guess you have no idea what that application's uninstaller is missing?  That is either an application which was Japanese, and you don't have the required language packs, that allow you to view characters.  You could likely find the registry key that contains that executable, difficult to say, the reason the path to the uninstaller is incorrect.  Performing an in-place install of Windows WILL NOT resolve that problem.

Comment: That may depend up the App and how it was installed, however, I added a Keep just Data section to my answer which has a much greater likelihood of solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the Windows troubleshooter:

- Download the
  [troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1)
- Run it and click the small Advanced link (not Next) to be able
  to clear the "Apply repairs automatically" box
- Click Next
- Click Uninstalling and wait for it to finish and give the list of
  all installed programs
- If you see this name in the list, click it and then Next
- Follow the on-screen instructions.

  - When it finishes, it gives the option to try uninstalling the program again.
  - It tells you it could not identify the problem and that you can give feedback on the program and to close it. However, you can click the link View detailed information to receive a report, so copy the details to your post
    for us to see.
  - After clicking next on the report screen, it will take you to a where you can select the repairs that you want to run on the program you want to uninstall. Ensure that the program is there and the check box marked.
  - Click next for it to run through these repairs.
  - You should then get a report if this was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

The message says that Windows cannot find the uninstaller.

One way to fix this is to properly install the App (if you know what it is), restart, and uninstall it. If you do not know it, this will not work.

The other way, then, is to run a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Generally Keep Everything works fine. Repair steps get more aggressive if this does not work.

If Keep Everything does not work, then you can try Keep only Data. This keeps Data and your User Profile (note that) and then you must reinstall your software.  If this is just a bad application then this approach will likely work.

Comment: I don't understand how reinstalling with the "keep everything" option is supposed to work. The program is (partially or fully) installed, but the uninstaller is missing. Reinstalling Windows can neither restore the missing uninstaller nor remove remains of the installed program. Reinstalling the program is a sound idea, but as you said it requires user to know the program. Reinstalling Windows with "keep only data" should work too, but unfortunately it's the nuclear option. I'm not sure how this will affect %appdata% and the problematic program may live there too.

Comment: Keep just data is not a nuclear option. Keep Nothing is the nuclear option. Keep data (because it keeps the user profile) makes reinstalling software fairly easy and quick. I have done all three.

Answer (score 0):

Enter into :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Get the menu and delete it.